What's the difference in HVAC air flow between cooling and heating? Heating causes me allergic reaction
As the weather turns cooler, my home HVAC automatically switches from cooling (during the day) to heating (over the night). The heating is using the gas burner. I had pretty obvious allergic reaction (blocked nose, sneezing, itchy eyes etc.) after the first night's heating. I didn't go outdoor and I know I am allergic to dust but not to any pollen/plant. I guess the heating air flow is different from the cooling and somehow disturbs the settled-down dust within the HVAC system and my nose detected it.
I will hire someone to do an air duct cleaning, but would that solve the problem? Does duct cleaning service clean the inside of the furnace? What else needs to be taken care of? Thanks!

what type of heating do you have? Gas, Electric, Heat-pump

"... I had pretty obvious allergic reaction (blocked nose, sneezing, itchy eyes etc.) after the first night's heating."
That statement is the key. The system does not direct air in a different pattern through different ducts. However often when the heat is use for the first time of the season, it will blow some dust off the heating coils that is released during the heating of the coils. ( In my home I actually get a slight burning smell)  This goes away in a few hours to a day or so. depending on how long the coils are actually hot.
Your system may heat a bit differently, but the idea is the same.  Give it some time to "self clean" and you may be fine.

Thanks! But the burning part and the actual hot air does not directly go into the duct right? The warmer air runs through the duct is heat exchanged, not the exhaust air, so there shouldn't be any smoke, right?

There can be a very minor amount of smoke, but that usually dissipates in  minutes. There is no "fire" as in the thought of flames.

I also get a slight smoke smell. I run my heat just prior to the season while the windows are still open.

@GuangYang think of dust in a hot frying pan ... the dust does not touch the stove burner, but it will burn after a while

@GuangYang buildup on the heat exchanger is burned off on the air side

Most likely you're experiencing what I would like to call the "first firing" of your heater. The heating elements sit in the same air stream as the cooling elements. As such, they can collect minor amounts of dust and debris. When you turn the heater on the first few times, it will "burn off" this dust. It can often create an initially smoky smell in your house (in extreme cases, it can set off smoke detectors). This smell will dissipate and not reoccur as long as the heater is regularly running.
I would assume an HVAC company can come out before you use your heater and clean these elements, which should prevent the smell from causing you issues.

Thanks! But as I commented above, the actual burning air does not go through the duct and get blown into the room, right?

Yes, it does.  Your HVAC system has the same airflow pattern whether cooling or heating (I mean, unless you have separate window units or something)—except in the heating unit.  Could be heat strips for a heat pump or natural gas burner unit in your furnace.  The "burning" air (i.e. burning dust) goes through the same ducts.  It stops after a while because the dust that has accumulated since the previous heating season has burned off.

@GuangYang There's dust inside your ductwork. Even if you change your filters as recommended, some dust will get in and accumulate during the time you're not using the heater. That's what's burning.
